# Update a string in a column based on conditions from a function in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to clean up a column that contains strings with more information than necessary. I tried searching for substrings or keywords and if found to replace with new string or keyword.

This is my df.

```
var1 = [('Car 1',1),
        ('Book',2),
        ('Apple cake',3),
        ('Tree',4),
        ('Horse',5),
        ('Car',1),
        ('Apple Tree',3),
        ('Book shelf',2),
        ('Books',2),
        ('Trees',4)]

df = pd.DataFrame(var1, columns = ['Item' , 'Code'])
```

What I'm trying is to loop trough each row in a column, check is a substring exists and if Yes, then replace with a new string. I cannot specify exactly the content of the string because it varies. And I cannot use the Code value because in many cases the code is absent.

This is the code I'm using

```
def item_check(string):
    if 'Car' in string:
        return 'Car'
    elif 'Book' in string:
        return 'Book'
    elif 'Apple' in string:
        return 'Apple'
    elif 'Tree' in string:
        return 'Tree'
    elif 'Horse' in string:
        return 'Horse'
    else:
        return ''

df['Item'] = df.apply(lambda x: item_check(df['Item']))
```

I expect the Item column to contain updated values:

```
Car
Book
Apple
Tree
Horse
Car
Apple
Book
Book
Tree
```

however I get NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nee to `apply` the method to the `Item` column. Hence do:

```
df['Item'] = df['Item'].apply(item_check)
```

Output:

```
    Item  Code
0    Car     1
1   Book     2
2  Apple     3
3   Tree     4
4  Horse     5
5    Car     1
6  Apple     3
7   Book     2
8   Book     2
9   Tree     4
```

Comment: Thank you harvpan! That was exactly the result I've been looking for!